# Determine the source of particular available package?

Tags: installation, apt, repository, installed-programs

Think you have a package which is installed or is available by apt or software manager. So you have it's repository already added.
Now you need help another user add needed repository.

How can I determine the repository which that package is available from?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
apt-cache policy <pkgname>
```

Example:

```
apt-cache policy wine
wine:
  Installed: 1.6~rc3-0ubuntu1
  Candidate: 1.6~rc3-0ubuntu1
  Version table:
 *** 1.6~rc3-0ubuntu1 0
        500 http://ppa.launchpad.net/ubuntu-wine/ppa/ubuntu/ raring/main amd64 Packages
        100 /var/lib/dpkg/status
     1.4.1-0ubuntu5 0
        500 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ raring/universe amd64 Packages
```

The version marked with `***` is the one actually installed.

Comment: This answer is better than mine.  1 it shows an intuitive url and 2 it shows other available versions.  Upvote.

Answer (score 1):

`apt-cache showpkg something` has a file field in the output.  The ppa is shown as part of that file field.